# syntax error testing simple audio on raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to run the simple example from simple audio on my raspberry pi but I got a syntax error

https://simpleaudio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

So on the root I have a file talking.wav and test.py. In test.py put in the first example and it work. When I try and play the talking.wav file with the second I get this syntax error

```
  File "test.py", line 3
    wave_obj = sa.WaveObject.from_wave_file(~/talking.wav)
                                                 ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here is the code:

```
import simpleaudio as sa

wave_obj = sa.WaveObject.from_wave_file(~/talking.wav)
play_obj = wave_obj.play()
play_obj.wait_done()
```

Answer (score 2):

The argument to the method `from_wave_file()` needs to be a string.

Maybe try adding quotes:

```
.from_wave_file('~/talking.wav')
```

or even add [`os.path.expanduser()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) like this:

```
import os
the_path = os.path.expanduser('~/talking.wav')
print(the_path)

.from_wave_file(the_path)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    wave_obj = sa.WaveObject.from_wave_file('~/talking.wav')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/simpleaudio/shiny.py", line 24, in from_wave_file
    wave_read = wave.open(wave_file, 'rb')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/wave.py", line 510, in open
    return Wave_read(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/wave.py", line 160, in __init__
    f = builtins.open(f, 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/talking.wav'

Comment: @gio_dude Well, the new error says "No such file or directory: '~/talking.wav' ". Do you have such a file and is it in the right location?

Comment: Yes when I type cd ~ then ls I see talking.wav

Comment: @gio_dude I edited my answer. Does the correct path show in my new code?

Comment: OK so i just run import os
the_path = os.path.expanduser('~/talking.wav')
print(the_path) it prints /root/talking.wav If plug that path in place of "~/talking.wav" same error

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    wave_obj = sa.WaveObject.from_wave_file('/root/talking.wav')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/simpleaudio/shiny.py", line 24, in from_wave_file
    wave_read = wave.open(wave_file, 'rb')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/wave.py", line 510, in open
    return Wave_read(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/wave.py", line 160, in __init__
    f = builtins.open(f, 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/talking.wav'

Comment: Found out I don't need to include the path just the file name if there the script and audio file is in the same location. It worked once I dropped the path.